# Shape and size of beard in Islam

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah, prophet-muhammad, sahaba

I see the [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/what-is-the-reason-or-wisdom-behind-the-rule-of-growing-beard-in-islam) discussed in this site which reveals the reason of growing beard and also the [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/507/is-it-more-important-to-grow-a-beard-or-to-avoid-resembling-non-muslims) discussed about importance of beard in islam.

I need to clarify some doubts about cutting of beard.

- Is it permissible to cut the beard lesser than the fist length?
- Someone says that leaving a small part is makrooh and shaving off the beard is haraam, is it so?
- I also heard that cutting the beard which is more than the size of a fist length is mushtahab, is it correct?
- what is the actual shape and length of beard that was allowed in Islam?
- Did the prophet(PBUH) or his companions cut their beard? yes means how much?

Comment: Too many questions put into one. Voting to close as too-broad.

Comment: Oh, yes @ Bleeding Finger, you are right, many questions...  I wish @ Muslim edit the question and delete some of extra questions. thnx

Answer (score 3):

### السَّلاَمُ عَلَيْكُمْ وَرَحْمَةُ اللهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

> Imam Nafi' (RA) further states, 'And ibn Umar, Radi-Allahu anhu,
>   during Hajj or Umrah used to hold on to his beard with his fist and
>   cut off whatever was in excess of that.' (Bukhari vol.2 pg.875;
>   Kitab-ul-Libas no.5892)
>
> Note: This hadith has also been narrated by Sayyiduna Abu Huraira
>   [Radhiallaahu anhu] and he is also reported to have trimmed his beard
>   beyond one fist.
>
> The verdict of the growing of the beard being wajib (obligatory) is
>   deduced from this hadith. That is because any explicit command of
>   Rasulullah  Sall-Allahu alayhi wa sallam will be regarded as wajib, if
>   there is no apparent, clear reason/proof which states that that
>   particular command is for istihbab (preference). This is an
>   established fact in usool-ul-fiqh (principles of jurisprudence).
>   Rasulullah  Sall-Allahu alayhi wa sallam has commanded the Ummah to
>   lengthen the beards. Allah Ta'ala has mentioned in the noble Qur'an,
>   'Those who disobey his (Rasulullah - Sallallaahu Alayhi Wasallam)
>   should beware of a trial or painful punishment that will afflict
>   them.' (Surah Noor 63)

There are many nash a saheeh about the beard shar'i we find, in the form of words of the Prophet (PBUH) Among the following arguments :

### حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ مِنْهَالٍ حَدَّثَنَا يَزِيدُ بْنُ زُرَيْعٍ حَدَّثَنَا عُمَرُ بْنُ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ زَيْدٍ عَنْ نَافِعٍ عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ قَالَ: خَالِفُوْا اْلمُشْرِكِيْنَ، وَوَفِّرُوْا الِّلْحىٰ وَأَحِفُّوْا الشَّوَارِبَ . رواه البخاري ومسلم

> "It has told us Muhammad ibn Olaya, has told us of Yazid ibn Zurai ',
>   has told us Umar bin Muhammad bin Zaid from Nafi' (the aide Ibn Umar)
>   from Ibn 'Umar from the Prophet who said:" Berbedalah you (not equal )
>   with idolaters, keep beard, and mustache was shaved. "[Sahih
>   al-Bukhari and Muslim]

### أَخْبَرَنِي الْعَلاَءُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمٰنِ بْنِ يَعْقُوبَ ـ مَوْلَى الْحُرَقَةِ ـ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ، قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ الله : جُزُّوا الشَّوَارِبَ وَأَرْخُوا اللِّحَىٰ. خَالِفُوا الْمَجُوسَ. [رواه مسلم

> "It has given me the news Ala 'bin Abdirahman bin al-Jacob-aide
>   Hurakah-from his father, from Abu Hurayrah said: the Prophet said:"
>   Shave was the mustache, beard guard, was different (not equal) Magians
>   people. "[Sahih Muslim]

### عَنْ عَبْدِ اللهِ بْنِ الزُّبَيْرِ عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ: عَشْرٌ مِنَ الْفِطْرَةِ: قَصُّ الشَّارِبِ،وَإِعْفَاءُ اللِّحْيَةِ، وَالسِّوَاكُ، وَاسْتِنْشَاقُ الْمَاءِ، وَقَصُّ الأَظْفَارِ، وَغَسْلُ الْبَرَاجِمِ، وَنَتْفُ الإِبِطِ، وَحَلْقُ الْعَانَةِ، وَانْتِقَاصُ الْمَاءِ. [رواه مسلم

> "It was narrated from Abdillah bin Zubair, narrated from Aisha, he
>   said: The Prophet said:" Ten things including nature: shave the
>   mustache, beard lengthened, cleansing his teeth, istinsyaq (insert
>   water into the nose), cutting the nails, washing between fingers,
>   plucking the armpit hairs, shaving the pubic hair and conserve water.
>   "[Sahih Muslim]

From the history above can be concluded that we are commanded to shave beards and mustaches. Thus instructed by the Apostle that we are different and do not match the idolaters-including Zoroastrianism, that is, people who worship fire where they like and even shave his beard until exhausted.

### أَخْبَرَنَا حَسَّانُ بْنُ عَطِيِّةَ عَنِ أَبِي مُنِيْبٍ الْجُرَشِيِّ عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ: مَنْ تَشَبَّهَ بِقَوْمٍ فَهُوَ مِنْهُمْ. [رواه أبو داود

> "It has been giving us news on Hassan ibn Abi Athiyah of Munib
>   al-Jurasyi of Ibn Umar said, The Prophet said:" Anyone who resembles a
>   people, then he belongs (group) them. "[Sahih Abu Dawud]

Moreover , the Prophet commands contain many elements of education for the Muslims so that they have their own personalities , both physically and spiritually from the others as infidels - idolaters . Differences were born to represent the identity of a people, in which case the beard became the identity or characteristic of the Muslims . Moreover, a lot of history surrounding this case by the scholars of hadith included in a separate chapter , the chapter held by human nature . Shaving the beard as well as the nature and resembles against women . As highlighted above , that beard signifies the perfection of man and distinguishes it from other types .

However , that does not mean we should not to shave his beard and hair done when it decomposes long , look beautiful and neat , and can even be frightening or disgusting anyone who saw it . Therefore thus allowed the beard to be shaved or trimmed . A history of Imam at - Tirmidhi that he values ​​Gharib , where the Prophet never cut his beard to look mostly flat and neat.

### أَخْبَرَنَا عُمَرُ بْنُ هَارُونَ، عَنْ أُسَامَةَ بن زَيْدٍ عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ شُعَيْبٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ عَنْ جَدِّهِ: أَنَّ النَّبِيِّ كَانَ يَأْخُدُ مِنْ لِحْيَتِهِ مِنْ عَرْضِهَا وَطُولِهَا . [رواه الترمذي

> "It has been giving us news on Umar ibn Harun of Usama bin Zaid bin
>   Amr Shu'aib from his father from his grandfather, that the Prophet's
>   beard to trim most of the same length." [Sahih at-Tirmidhi]

In response to this problem the scholars , both mutaqaddimin ( previous ) or muta'akhirin ( later ) a lot of different opinions. Hanafi and Hanbali scholars circles firmly says that a person is unlawful to cut his beard until exhausted , even he is required to pay diyat ( ransom ) . Being Shafi'i and Maliki scholars say that the law limited only makrooh. Imam Nawawi representing Shafi said , " shaving , cutting , and burning beard is makrooh. Meanwhile, trim the excess and smoothed it is a good deed . Leave it for a month long is makrooh , as makruhnya cut and cut it . " ( Sharh Saheeh Muslim : vol . 3 : 151 ) . Furthermore, the scholars are still at odds over the length of the beard to be cut , although there is a history that tells us that Abu Huraira and Abdullah bin Omar used to trim the beard when it has exceeded the length of the palm of the hand . However , some scholars do not specify a certain length , but quite cut appropriately . Hasan al -Basri , an ordinary tabi'in trim and shave his beard , to looking good and presentable .

From the above it can be concluded that the beard trim or cut off part of the law is permissible . Moderate to shave until exhausted its legal is makruh , but not to the degree unlawful . The preserve is sunnah .

Sorry for my english.

[Source](http://www.fatwatarjih.com/2012/11/hukum-jenggot-dan-cadar.html) (in bahasa indonesia)