# Is shaving the beard Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, uloom-al-hadith, human-body, beard, shaving

Is shaving the beard Haram? Is there any authentic hadith about it?
What is the opinion of the Quran about it? (Sunni and Shia)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shape and size of beard in Islam](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5395/shape-and-size-of-beard-in-islam)

Answer (score 9):

Growing the beard is mandatory for all males; And our prophet(SAW) 's Sunnah shows it:

> - The ruler of Yemen, appointed by the Persian emperor Kisra, sent two
>     envoys to the Messenger (Peace and blessings be upon him) to summon
>     him. When they came into his presence, he noticed that they had shaved
>     their beards and grew their moustaches. He hated to look at them
>     (because of their odd appearance) and he said: "Woe be to you, who
>     told you to do so?" They replied: "Our lord! (Referring to Kisra.)"
>     The Messenger (Peace and blessings be upon him) then said: "But my
>     Lord, may He be exalted and glorified, has commanded me to leave alone
>     my beard and to trim my moustache." [Judged to be Hasan (good) by
>     Al-Albani.]
> - "The Messenger (Peace and blessings be upon him) used to have a large
>     beard." [Muslim]

Also In many Hadiths, the prophet (SAW) recommend men to leave alone their beards; such as:

> - "Trim the moustache and save the beard." [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]
> - "Cut your moustaches and leave your beards alone. Be different from
>     the people of the scripture." [Muslim]
> - "Be different from the Mushrikin (those who worship other than Allah);
>     trim your moustaches and save your beards." [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]
> - And prophet said:"Allah curses those men who imitate the women, and He
>     curses those women who imitate the men." [Al-Bukhari]

And pay attention The beard is a major distinction between men and women.

So as Allah said in Quran that we should obey prophet("He who obeys the Messenger has obeyed Allah..."[**Surat An-Nisā',verse80**]),men should Trim the moustache and save their beard.

Also there are this documents in **Shia view**:

> - It is reported in Bihar al-Anwar in the chapter concerning the beard
>     (Kitab al-Mahasin) in which:Imam Musa b. Ja’far, al-Kazim (as) was
>     asked:“Is it recommended to wear the beard?” he said: “Yes”, then he
>     was asked: “Is it permissible for one to shave one’s beard?”, Imam
>     (as) replied: “It is permissible to shave the sides of the face where
>     the beard grows, however, to shave the front (chin) is not
>     permissible”.
> - Imam al-Sadiq (as) states: “If the hair (on the mans face) were not to
>     grow within a specific given period, would the male not remain in a
>     state like that of the young immature boy and a female?, And as a
>     result of this, the male would not command any respect nor esteem”.
> - Imam al-Sadiq (as) states: “From amongst the laws of the Lord of the
>     Universe was that He granted the male gender from amongst the humans a
>     beard so that there may be a difference (in appearance) between them”.

Also Shaykh al-Baha’iy, al-Damad and Kashif al-Ghita’ are grand Shi’ite jurists, who have given rulings to the unlawfulness of the shaving of the beard, based on consensus, in their books al-I’tiqadat and Resalah al-Shar’ al-Muqadas.

Comment: I asked about the view of Sunni and Shia, so your narrations are almost about sunni, would you please give me more info. about the view of shia too?  thnx a lot.

Comment: Nothing about your answer actually concludes to "beard is mandatory". That is a far fetched interpretation from the sources you posted.