# Tidying beard by trimming allowed?

Tags: taharah, men, fitrah

Muslim men are told to leave the beard and trim the moustache. There is some discussion whether you can trim more than a fistful of the beard. Besides that can you trim the hairs if they are sticking out or growing unequally for example? Or are you just supposed to leave and keep as "tidy" as possible by combing and using beard oil to press the hair together?

Secondly can you remove the hair on the neck? Does this constitute the beard area?

Comment: Related http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13087/is-shaving-the-beard-haram if not a duplicate!

Comment: There is difference of opinion on this issue. Some say you can't take any hair from beard, some say you can make it look good by as little trimming as possible. As long as you are satisfied by the either of this view to be true sunnah and follows that, you will get your reward from Allah, inshallah. I personally prefer not to trim anything from it. And i don't look liek gorilla :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have a beard. Some people say it’s just a sunnah and not compulsory. However, the Prophet of Allah (Peace be upon him) ordered us by saying cut the moustache short and leave the beard. So you should not trim the beard and try to keep it looking clean by applying oil and combing it etc. And Allah says in the Quran “Obey Allah and Obey the messenger.” So we should obey what the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) told us to do and keep our beards. Also I have seen some imams completely shave their moustache off. This is not what the Prophet (Peace be upon him) told us to do. He told us to keep it short, not shave it off.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thank you for the answer. It could benefit from provided exact external sources and citing specific [evidence](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer) to support your answer.

Answer (score -6):

Having a beard is sunnah and isn't mandatory. Just because the rasul did it doesn't mean u have to. As long as you don't look bad then trim it otherwise you will look like a gorilla. Muslims need to be clean, therefore trimming your beard so it looks clean.

Comment: So our prophet sunnah is looking as "gorilla" ?! FYI, most islamic scholars agreed that beard is a MUST, not just sunnah