# Is growing a beard only appropriate for the elderly?

Tags: islamic-basis, beard, age

[According](https://www.rferl.org/a/turkmenistan-beards-crackdown-flights-forcible-shaving/32421154.html) to RFERL, in Turkmenistan

> Mosque-goers say imams have begun preaching to their congregations that growing a beard is only appropriate for older men who have reached retirement age.

I see that there are some/several Q [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13087/is-shaving-the-beard-haram) that suggest that growing a beard can be deemed as recommended in Islam. But is there anything that suggests the interpretation in the quoted para, i.e. that it's only appropriate for the elderly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The basis for prescribing beards in Islam are the ahadith:

> #### ‏ انهكوا الشوارب، وأعفوا اللحى
>
> Cut the mustaches short and leave the beard (as it is).
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5893)</sup>

> #### عشر من الفطرة قص الشارب وإعفاء اللحية والسواك واستنشاق الماء وقص الأظفار وغسل البراجم ونتف الإبط وحلق العانة وانتقاص الماء
>
> Ten are from the Fitrah: Trimming the mustache, leaving the beard to grow, Siwak, cleaning the nose with water, cutting the fingernails, washing the knuckles, plucking the underarm hair, shaving the pubic hairs, and Intiqas with water.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:261a)</sup>

These ahadith do not put any preconditions or mention any exceptions. Hence the apparent meaning is that it is prescribed to keep beards for everyone who is able. If it was only meant for the elderly then that should have been explicitly stated in the hadith.

Further, a beard grows naturally after puberty. If it was inappropriate for youngsters to keep it then cutting it should have been listed along with removal of pubic hair, armpit hair, fingernails and mustaches in the above hadith or its variants.

Finally, the claim itself is easily disproved from examples: The Prophet ﷺ died at the age of around 60 years ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5900)) and there is evidence that he had a beard years before that such as at the treaty of Hudaibiyah ([Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2765)), or during the drought ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1033)),  or when leading congregational prayers  ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:760)) etc. So he definitely had a beard before what is now called the 'retirement' age.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no specific age limit or requirement for growing a beard in Islam.** The act of growing a beard is highly encouraged in Islam and is considered a part of the natural disposition and beauty of a man. The beard is considered a sign of masculinity and a symbol of religious devotion. **The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) himself had a beard and encouraged his companions to grow one. There are several hadiths that emphasize the importance of growing a beard in Islam:**

> • Abu Hurairah (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the
> Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "Trim the mustache and let
> the beard grow. Be different from the Jews and the Christians."
> (Narrated by Bukhari and Muslim)
>
> • Ibn Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet
> Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "Differentiate yourselves from the
> Mushrikeen (polytheists); let the beard grow and trim the mustache."
> (Narrated by Bukhari)
>
> • Abdullah ibn Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the
> Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "Do the opposite of what
> the polytheists do; let your beards grow and trim your mustaches."
> (Narrated by Muslim)

Based on these hadiths, it is clear that **growing a beard is strongly encouraged in Islam** and is not limited to any specific age group. It is a practice that is recommended for all Muslim men who are physically capable of growing one. Therefore, it is not appropriate to assume that growing a beard is only appropriate for the elderly in Islam.

In conclusion, growing a beard is a recommended practice in Islam that is not limited by age. Muslim men are encouraged to grow a beard as a sign of religious devotion and to differentiate themselves from non-Muslims. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) himself had a beard, and his companions followed in his footsteps by growing one. Thus, it is appropriate for Muslim men of all ages to grow a beard as long as they are physically capable of doing so.

[Note]

*Regarding the matter of keeping a beard, it is worth noting that there are varying scholarly opinions on this topic within the Islamic faith. According to some scholars, **shaving one's beard is considered "haram" or a forbidden act in Islam.** However, **it is important to acknowledge that there is no unanimous agreement among scholars on this matter**, and the interpretation of what constitutes a proper beard length can vary between individuals and regions.
Furthermore, it is important to understand that the scholars who are in favor of keeping a beard believe that it is a Sunnah, or an action that is obligatory according to Islamic law. These scholars often cite various religious texts and traditions that highlight the importance of having a beard for men.
In any case, the decision to keep or shave one's beard is ultimately a personal one and may be influenced by a variety of factors, including cultural norms, personal preferences, and religious beliefs. Ultimately, it is up to each individual to seek guidance from Islamic scholars and make an informed decision that aligns with their values and beliefs.*

Comment: The last paragraph has contradictions - "*shaving one's beard is considered haram*" and then "*but not obligatory according to Islamic law*". If shaving it is haram then it is obligatory to keep it. Also note that it is not 'some' but the vast majority who consider shaving it to be haram, some like [Ibn Hazm](https://shamela.ws/book/12446/151) and [Ibn Abideen](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/1074) even claimed consensus on it.

Comment: @UmU I fixed it.