# Is there is any Hadith about the limit of cutting beard?

Tags: beard

From my knowledge I am not read or learn any Hadith about the limit of beard. I have a little beard. Some people says that you must want to put beard that define limit of four Imam. But I disagree(Ikhtilaf) with them.
Can I Reject the rules of them? 
Is there is any Hadith about the limit of beard? Any further lecture on beard from (S.A.W) or any of his Companian?

Comment: Are you looking for evidences for beard that scholars use? If so this is a duplicate question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/230/what-does-islam-say-about-growing-beards.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

According to my research there is no disagreement (ikhtilaf) of our four imam on bread. Every imam have a bread in the limit of one hand. There are also the bread of 1 lac and 24 thousand prophet and also the 1 lac and 24 thousand sahaba. There are also the hadith about the limit of bread. Bread is THE sunnah of Holy Prophet (S.A.W).

Comment: Bread is the sunnah of every Prophet. But there is no hadith on limit of one hand beard. Limit was suggested by four Imam not prove by any Hadith.

Comment: now see the picture if y0u under stand arabic and also see the book and page number

Comment: I am disagree(Ikhtilaf) with four imam. Show me If any Hadith are there. I want Hadith not book of four Imam. Is there is any Hadith?

Comment: see the black line . This is hadith and the word in circle is the name of big hadith books and also the umh answer you

Answer (score 0):

Understand that the Imams do not give their opinions on whims but base it on evidence and principles of interpreting that evidence.

The evidence for not cutting the beard less than a fist includes the hadith narrated by Ibn Umar and his implementation of it:

> عن ابن عمر، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال ‏ "‏ خالفوا المشركين، وفروا اللحى، وأحفوا الشوارب ‏"‏‏.‏ وكان ابن عمر إذا حج أو اعتمر قبض على لحيته، فما فضل أخذه‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Do the opposite of what the pagans do. Keep the beards and cut the mustaches short". Whenever Ibn Umar performed the Hajj or Umra, he used to hold his beard with his hand and cut whatever remained outside his hold.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari , كتاب اللباس](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/109)</sup>